# Goal "sonar:sonar" does not exist in this project

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I am using maven 1.0.2 to build a java project in jenkins.I am trying to configure sonar report for this project.I am using Sonar version 4.0.I get below error when i fire the build:

[Project_Sonar] $ /MyPath/maven-1.0.2/bin/maven -f /MyPath/workspace/Project_Sonar/maven.xml -e -B sonar:sonar -Dsonar.jdbc.driver=org.postgresql.Driver -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://sonardb.example.com:5534/sonar ******** ******** -Dsonar.host.url=http://example.com:8093/sonar ******** ******** -Dmaven.repo.local=/Mypath/workspace/Project_Sonar/.repository
BUILD FAILED
Goal "sonar:sonar" does not exist in this project.

Can anyone help?

Regards,
Inderpreet Kaur

Answer (score 0):

You will have to [update Maven to a newer version](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+Maven); if I recall correctly, with SonarQube 4.0 you will need at least Maven 3.0.x.

I recommend using the latest version available (3.3.x as of writing), as new versions of Maven often fix class loading issues that can cause errors at analysis time.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I'll discuss the same with my team.